The comparison of public keys corresponding to signatures based on secp256k1
Can two signatures based on the elliptic curve secp256k1 be compared to determine if they use the same public key without recovering the public keys?

The signature and message are given

Don't use secp256k1, it's not widely supported. Use P-256 (a.k.a. secp256r1, prime256v1).

You haven't specified which digital signature scheme to use. ECDSA will be assumed in this answer.
SEC#1 v2.0 section 4.1.6 specifies a procedure that recovers the public key from a message and its signature. Using this, you can compare whether 2 public keys from 2 msg-sig pair are same, additively complementary, or otherwise distinct.
